# Googlebot substitutes the links of Rails app with subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, robots.txt, googlebot

I have this Rails app, with domain name `abc.com`. I am also having a separate subdomain for Piwik stats, in this subdomain `stats.abc.com`.

Googlebot somehow listed some of the links with my subdomain too.

```
http://abc.com/login
http://stats.abc.com/login
http://abc.com/signup
http://stats.abc.com/signup
```

The ones with `stats` will reference to the same page in the app, but are treated entirely different website.

I have put in `robots.txt` in `stats` after this matter, but wondering if there is any appropriate way to block this because I may have new subdomains in future. Here's my content in `robots.txt`

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robots.txt will block it just fine. It's just important to remember BEFORE you publish a site - Google is pretty fast. Some search engines ignore robots.txt. Best thing to do is not have subdomains that don't really fit you situation. I recommend reading the true purpose of subdomains. You should not be serving the same site on different domains. You should use a 301 direct or have different contents on different (sub)domains... Unless stats.abc.com contains different material, it shouldn't be a subdomain. What exactly do you need so many subdomains for?

You *could* detect the user-agent, and if it's a bot, return a 404 too

Comment: I have subdomains for blog, support, etc. which are of different app (Wordpress, Piwik, PHP).

Comment: Yeah... that's pretty bad practice. You should have domain.com/blog, domain.com/support. If they are hosted on separate servers, you should have a distributed system... You can set up virtual hosts if they are all on the same server... For 1.) you wont get the SEO you want from your blog on your root domain. You want traffic to domain.com, not blog.domain.com, which is what you'll get

Comment: I have already set up virtual hosts for these subdomains which are on the same server. But I thought my practice on subdomains are general practices? Thanks for your opinions.

Comment: support emails should come from you@support.domain.com. support url should be domain.com/support UNLESSSSSS support is a SYSTEM meaning that users can self-help themselves and you have built an AI to handle user questions, etc.